# (solved: method factor) Does low cross-type covariances (compared to within-type cross-factor) imply a bad measure?

Tags: covariance, structural-equation-modeling, psychometrics

I'm not sure about the right terminology, but here goes.

I have a questionnaire measure (30 likert-items) that has been traditionally divided into five six-item factors. Each factor has two different types of items, which represent two different approaches to formulate the questions (basically, one asks how you feel about the thing in principle, the other asks you to judge examples related to the thing).

I collected some data, and had a poor-ish fit for my SEM (RMSEA .078), which prompted me to look for what's wrong. I ended up trying a model that separates the two types for each factor into a factor of their own, resulting in a 10-factor model (with only three items per factor). I don't know much about psychometrics, but I would intuitively imagine that if the original factors are actually valid, the covariances between the two separated factors (that are supposed to represent the same theoretical construct) should be higher than, say, the covariances between different factors. I found the opposite:

[image]

(I've listed here all the factor-factor covariances and marked what kind of relationship the factors have: "group" means covariance between factors that are theoretically linked; "type" means the two types of questions, denoted as _j and _r in the factor names; w and x are within and cross.)

My intuition - without much expertise - says that there is something wrong with this measure. Is this kind of comparison meaningful at all? Do you agree with my intuition? If so, what could be wrong with the measure? Any suggestions for how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you might have some method factors that you need to account for. These are dealt with in CFA using multi-trait multi-method (MTMM) models.

I don't think it means you have a bad measure.

Comment: Thanks. Can you point me to a good source on method factors and MTMM?

Comment: https://www.socialresearchmethods.net/kb/mtmmmat.php